# Select collection's items where state is "running" or "paused"

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I need to create a list with all my containers (that are stored in the collection InfosContainers) with the state "running" or "paused" but I don't know how to make the request.

I have tried this one:

```
containersRngPsd = InfosContainers.find({stateContainer: "running" || stateContainer: "paused"});
```

But I have an error:

```
imports/ui/chart.js:43:87: Unexpected token, expected , (43:87)
```

So my request is false. Someone could help me to make my request works ?

Comment: use $or: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Mongo's `$or` syntax:

```
InfosContainers.find( { $or: [ { stateContainer: "running" }, { stateContainer: "paused" } ] } )
```

Comment: Yes thank you to you and @felix I'll mark the answer but I need to wait before

Comment: I have a question, does your command return me all the items that are "running" or "paused" ? Because if I do `console.log(containersRngPsd)` I have "LocalCollection cursor" then we I try containersRngPsd.length it returns me "undefined" ??

Comment: @Jerome you get the cursor's length with `.count()` instead of `.length`.

Comment: Okay so you know why the count return me 0 despite I have 1 container with the state "running"

Comment: is the property `"state"` or `"stateContainer"`?

Comment: `stateContainer` and I have 2 with the running state

Comment: Oh I have founded why ! Just forgot the subscribe on the specific page !

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$in` instead of `$or` for readability and performance reasons.

```
InfosContainers.find( { stateContainer: {$in: ["running", "paused" ] } )
```

It may not matter in your case, but I think I just wanted to add this in case people perform queries on larger data set.

When the column is not indexed there is a significant performance difference.

MongoDB recommends $in over $or.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in

Comment: Oh thank you for the input, anyway I have indexed my columns because the name of the container is unique + his id too